# How to 'adjust' a series mean to match another series mean

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means

I have 2 data series that I would like to compare. Perhaps it's best to show a graphic of the series as they are now ...

[image: What I have now]

and what I would like to do ...

[image: What I'd like]

Basicaly, I would like to visually compare the red series to the blue as shown in image 2. The length of the blue series is 20 and red series length is 31. I guess I have to 'adjust' the mean of the red series, to the mean of the first 20 points in the blue series.

May I ask where I start please ? I really don't know what to search for on SE / google in order even begin. Could you point me in the right direction, please ?

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: If you have a set of points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\dots$, then you can shift all points vertically downwards by subtracting all $y$ coordinates by a positive constant $a$ to get the set $(x_1,y_1-a),(x_2,y_2-a),\dots$. If the mean of the $y$ coordinates of the first set was $\bar{y}$, then the mean of the $y$ coordinates of the second set will be $\bar{y}-a$.

Comment: @Bruce Zheng. Mmmmm, seems embrassingly simple. Thankyou.